# Reading file on client machine from server

Tags: java

I have added functionality which will enable the user to attach a file from web page.
and this file will be sent as an attachment to another user.
When I try this on my local machine it works fine.
I deployed the application on the server.
And when I am trying to attach a file its throwing FileNotFoundException.
Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

You seems to  be reading file system assuming that client is always on server.

Server and Client are different things. Client may be / May not be [all most all the time] on server. You need to upload file then read..

If you can read client's flle system this easily, then we might not have coined the word security

Comment: Thanks for looking into it.
I am relatavely new to java.
Can you give a sample code to upload file on server and then read it.

Comment: Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Part two is attachment
        messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = 
          new FileDataSource(new File(fileName));
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(
          new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName("SWIFT.msg");
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // Put parts in message
        message.setContent(multipart);

        // Send the message
        Transport.send( message );

Comment: The variable fileName contains path. It is running fine on local server but not from remote server. Its throwing FileNotFound exception. Can you give a sample code for uploading file on the server.